# Selecting multiple rows in attribute table. Help formulating equation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table

I have some GPS data that I'm working with. I would like to highlight multiple points within the track over a specific time period. For example, the track started at 10:32:03 AM and ended at 11:28:02 AM. Within that time period, I would like to highlight the points between 10:45:38 AM and 10:59:21 AM. How would I go about doing this? I saw the "Select by Attribute" option and I imagine that this will be the way I want to go about this. I'm having trouble writing a formula/equation to do this though. Could anyone help me out with this? Or if there's an easier way to do it, that'd be great too.

Comment: Can you add a picture that shows exactly how the date-time field is formatted?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned "Select by Attribute", I'll assume you're using ArcGIS. If your time values are stored in a datetime field (as opposed to a text, integer, or other field type) you can do this using the Less Than and Greater Than operators. Less than works as "earlier than" for time values, and greater than is "later than". Greater than/less than can also work on time values stored in text or integer fields but you may get unexpected results depending on how your time values are formatted.

To use a pair of times as a start and stop point for your selection, you would format your query like this (I used the times from your comment):

```
yourTimeField > date '2016-03-31 17:40:02' AND yourTimeField < date '2016-03-31 17:41:02'
```

I'm pretty sure this doesn't work for shapefiles, a Date field in a shapefile can only contain dates, not times. [The ArcGIS help goes into a lot more detail](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000), the format for querying by date and time varies depending on the format your data is stored in.

Comment: @SRPang See my edit above. Dates take a little more work to use as a selection criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've still been unsuccessful in isolating specific parts of my track. The data are stored as .gpx files. The dates for the files that I'll be using will all be the same. All of the tracks take place over 1 day. I was unable to find any other time values besides the ones attached to the date which is why I'm using them. @Dan C

Comment: @SRPang It sounds like the best way forward is to convert your GPX to a more GIS-friendly format, like a shapefile, then create a new field to store your time values and select records using that field.

Comment: I converted my .gpx files to .shp files but when I examine the attribute table, the time is still in the DateTime format. How would I go about modifying this?